# How to save/make remain the state of radio buttons on bootstrap popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, popover

I have this issue when I decided to put radio buttons on bootstrap popovers. In my html, there is 4 buttons that will be displayed and each button have their own list of selections which consists of radio buttons. So when I clicked one of the buttons a popover will show and then I clicked one of the radio buttons on the popover, after the popover closed and when I try again to see the popover the radio button I select does not now checked. Why is that happening? My code is as follows:

```
jQuery('.btn-finishing-types').each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.popover({
        container: "#setup-form",
        placement: "right",
        content: $this.parent().find('.list-container-wrapper').html(),
        html: true
    }).on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        jQuery('.btn-finishing-types').popover('hide');



    });
});
```

Comment: Personally I would just show/hide the radio buttons in a selection field. however, it doesn't look as if you're actually doing anything when the radio button is selected. If you could include an html snippet that would be helpful.

Comment: i made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8P7mc/